# Calculate AUC in Java

Tags: java, roc, auc

is there a simple library to calculate the Area Under the ROC Curve (AUC) in JAVA, given a set of Precision-Recall pairs, such as:

1.0  0.0

0.9  0.1

0.8  0.1

...

It could take in input two arrays of double.

I could also write it myself, but if there exists an already consolidated library it would be better.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found two potential libraries and since I haven't used either, I tracked down information on the first that indicates that it has been used and endorsed.

http://mark.goadrich.com/programs/AUC/ This one seems to have been endorsed [here.](http://metaoptimize.com/qa/questions/267/code-for-auc-area-under-the-receiver-operating-characteristic-curve)

http://weka.wikispaces.com/Area+under+the+curve

Comment: The problem is that the first one requires the number of positive examples and negative examples, whereas the second works only in conjunction with weka classifiers. I have just a list of precision-recall pairs.

Answer (score -3):

AUC = (recall + specificity) / 2

i.e. you need to calculate the 'specificity':
specificity = tn / (fp + tn)

In other words you need to know at least tn, fp and recall ( = tp / (tp + fn)).